# Getting parent that does not contain child with attribute value

Tags: jquery

I have N DIV's. Each represent a physical computer. Each DIV can have N UL elements. Each UL represents software type installed on server. And finally each UL element contains N LI elements representing data related to software (UL).

I want to select a server that does not contain LI element with certain data (data is represented as data-id attribute on LI element)

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf66ouvo/) to work on that and using .not() (line 3 in javascript window):

But it always returns both servers not matter what input provided

```
$('.srv').not('li[data-id="2"]').each(function(){
    servers += $(this).attr('id') + ', ';
});
```

Comment: In fiddle I only see srv1, what must be the output?

Comment: `$('.srv').not(':has(li[data-id="2"])').each(function() { ... })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
 $(".srv:not(:has(li[data-id=2]))")
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9b6sx5jn/)**

Comment: It returns srv1,srv2,srv2. Expected output is srv2